# 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        instance = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        user = instance.post_user
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(comment_post=instance.pk)
        context['comments']['profile'] = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        return context
```

This is my view so far. When i use that code i get this error 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment. How do i attach the line below correctly?

```
context['comments']['profile'] = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
```

Comment: `context['profile'] = Profile.objects.get(user=user)` ??

Comment: Im trying to attach user that left the comment. By doing this i will attach user of post

Comment: But you *don't* attach the user that left the comment anyway. `user` is *always* the post_user, because you never define it to be anything else. Are you sure you need to do this at all? Does the Comment have a link to the user that created it? You should show the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is that value of `context['comments']` is not a dictionary but QuerySet object.
So you can't do:
`context['comments']['profile'] = Profile.objects.get(user=user)`.

Maybe you can add relation with Profile model right to the Comment model, like:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, ...)
    ...
```

So then you can have access to the value of Profile who left a comment.